# Zod: Reusing field multiple times

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

I have a large schema that represents a cluster with many data tiers:

hot
warm
cold
frozen

Each of this properties contains an array of nodes, the content of hot,war,cold,frozen is the same type. I can't figure out how can I reuse this node type to avoid repeating.

```
const nodesOut = z.object({
  zone: z.string(),
  hot: z.array(
    z.object({
      jvm: z.object({
        mem: z.object({
          heap_used_in_bytes: z.number(),
          heap_used_percent: z.number(),
        }),
      }),
      fs: z.object({
        total: z.object({
          total_in_bytes: z.number(),
          free_in_bytes: z.number(),
          available_in_bytes: z.number(),
        }),
      }),
      indices: z.object({
        mappings: z.object({
          total_count: z.number(),
          total_estimated_overhead_in_bytes: z.number(),
        }),
      }).optional(),
      attributes: z.object({
        data: z.string().optional(),
        availability_zone: z.string(),
        server_name: z.string(),
      }),
    })
  ).optional(),
  warm: z.array(
    z.object({
      jvm: z.object({
        mem: z.object({
          heap_used_in_bytes: z.number(),
          heap_used_percent: z.number(),
        }),
      }),
      fs: z.object({
        total: z.object({
          total_in_bytes: z.number(),
          free_in_bytes: z.number(),
          available_in_bytes: z.number(),
        }),
      }),
      indices: z.object({
        mappings: z.object({
          total_count: z.number(),
          total_estimated_overhead_in_bytes: z.number(),
        }),
      }).optional(),
      attributes: z.object({
        data: z.string().optional(),
        availability_zone: z.string(),
        server_name: z.string(),
      }),
    })
  ).optional(),
  cold: z.array(
    z.object({
      jvm: z.object({
        mem: z.object({
          heap_used_in_bytes: z.number(),
          heap_used_percent: z.number(),
        }),
      }),
      fs: z.object({
        total: z.object({
          total_in_bytes: z.number(),
          free_in_bytes: z.number(),
          available_in_bytes: z.number(),
        }),
      }),
      indices: z.object({
        mappings: z.object({
          total_count: z.number(),
          total_estimated_overhead_in_bytes: z.number(),
        }).optional(),
      }),
      attributes: z.object({
        data: z.string().optional(),
        availability_zone: z.string(),
        server_name: z.string(),
      }),
    })
  ).optional(),
  frozen: z.array(
    z.object({
      jvm: z.object({
        mem: z.object({
          heap_used_in_bytes: z.number(),
          heap_used_percent: z.number(),
        }),
      }),
      fs: z.object({
        total: z.object({
          total_in_bytes: z.number(),
          free_in_bytes: z.number(),
          available_in_bytes: z.number(),
        }),
      }),
      indices: z.object({
        mappings: z.object({
          total_count: z.number(),
          total_estimated_overhead_in_bytes: z.number(),
        }),
      }).optional(),
      attributes: z.object({
        data: z.string().optional(),
        availability_zone: z.string(),
        server_name: z.string(),
      }),
    })
  ).optional(),
});
```

I read about recursive schemas but this is not actually recursive. What's the best way to go?

Thanks

https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#recursive-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Jacob from zod github:
https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/discussions/1631

This is the solution:

```js
const node = z.object({
  jvm: z.object({
    mem: z.object({
      heap_used_in_bytes: z.number(),
      heap_used_percent: z.number(),
    }),
  }),
  fs: z.object({
    total: z.object({
      total_in_bytes: z.number(),
      free_in_bytes: z.number(),
      available_in_bytes: z.number(),
    }),
  }),
  indices: z
    .object({
      mappings: z
        .object({
          total_count: z.number(),
          total_estimated_overhead_in_bytes: z.number(),
        })
        .optional(),
    })
    .optional(),
  attributes: z.object({
    data: z.string().optional(),
    availability_zone: z.string(),
    server_name: z.string(),
    logical_availability_zone: z.string(),
  }),
});

const nodesIn = z.object({
  nodes: z.record(node),
});

const nodesOut = z.object({
  zone: z.string(),
  hot: z.array(node).optional(),
  warm: z.array(node).optional(),
  cold: z.array(node).optional(),
  frozen: z.array(node).optional(),
});

type NodesInType = z.TypeOf<typeof nodesIn>;
type NodesOutType = z.TypeOf<typeof nodesOut>;
```